# Trouble entering native full screen on iphone 13 pro device with ios 17 safari

Tags: ios, reactjs, mobile-safari

On ios safari, I'm encountering an issue when I try to enter into full screen mode with a `<video>` element via

`videoRef.current.webkitEnterFullScreen();`

We're using srcObject to assign a media stream to the `<video>` element, which has `playsinline` and `autoplay` attributes. I confirmed that the `'loadeddata'` and `'lodadedmetadata'` events are firing on the `<video>` element before trying to enter full screen and that the `webkitEnterfullScreen()` invoke is being triggered as a direct result of a user action (click). Also confirmed that the video is in readyState 4, is playing, the `srcOjbect` is present, and that full screen is enabled (`video.webkitSupportsFullscreen`). No errors or console warnings are being thrown when we invoke `webkitEnterfullScreen()` - nothing whatsoever happens. The same code works just fine on iphone 13 pro emulator running ios 16.4
Wondering if the upgrade to ios 17 might've broken `webkitEnterFullScreen()` ? Here's the full function for toggling to full screen with an added try-catch:

```
export function toggleFullscreen(video: WebkitVideoElement) {
    if (screenfull.isEnabled) {
        screenfull.toggle();
    } else if (!useIsFullscreen.getState() && 'webkitEnterFullScreen' in video) {
        try {
            video.webkitEnterFullScreen();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error name:', err.name);
            console.log('Error message:', err.message);
        }
    }
}
```

Every so often it seems to work randomly but I can't confirm that because it happens so sporadically and in weird states i.e. refresh or navigate back then forward

Answer (score -2):

I would try thinking about how safari interacts with your code... go one line at a time trying to figure out why each thing happens I don't code in python (I code in C#) but this would be viatal if you're trying to fullscreen on safari

Comment: This answer may be better off as a comment, since it doesn't really "answer" the question, more give diagnosis advice